# How can epigenetic changes be erased if they are inherited?

Tags: terminology, epigenetics

I’m a little bit confused about DNA methlyation reprogramming and about the nature of an epigenetic phenomenon. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reprogramming):

> After fertilization the paternal and maternal genomes are once again demethylated and remethylated (except for differentially methylated regions associated with imprinted genes). This reprogramming is likely required for totipotency of the newly formed embryo and **erasure of acquired epigenetic changes**.

I don't understand how something can be thought to be both heritable and erasable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster has already answered the biological question by his own research, for which he is to be commended. He can find the origin of the term in a similar way, but that is not biology.

Comment: @David Are you kidding? There is a terminology tag on this website. Maybe I should have use it, but I don't think my question deserves to be closed for that.

Comment: The tags that people use do not define the purpose of this site or the acceptability of questions. This is explained in the [Help on Asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Questions on why something has such and such a name are generally of little interest to biology, except for its history, and, in any case you show no evidence of trying to find definitions yourself. A Google search for "Epigenetics Definition" includes a definition by Robin Holliday that might remove the unstated and erroneous assumption of your own on the meaning of the word.

Comment: @David - there is definitely important misunderstanding still present in the question that was not addressed by the OP, and it seems this is a misunderstanding you have as well. I see absolutely no reason to close this question, because even if its title seems to be about semantics an appropriate answer would not need to be.

Comment: @David All the websites and sources I used before posting this question mentioned that "Epigenetics is the study of **heritable** changes in gene function that do not involve changes in the DNA sequence." (This comes from the wikipedia article about epigenetics, but this isn't the only source that mentions the heritable character of epigenetics phenomena). I know that we are supposed to make some efforts before asking anything here, and that's what I did. Unfortunately, I didn't find your Robin Holliday definition before, so sorry about that. In all cases, I still think my question matters.

Comment: @BryanKrause — It is not just the title that is about semantics, it is the concluding sentence in the question, clearly meant as the key question because it is in bold. There may be interesting answers on epigenetics, but they need a clear biological question first. This is not.

Comment: @David The answer is because some portion of epigenetic changes are indeed heritable. How would you propose the questioner reframe their question to fit your narrow view of what makes a good question here? Their curiosity is clearly based on the biology of the situation. SE English language and usage is not for scientific terminology.

Comment: (1942) "Biology. of or relating to epigenesis, or the successive differentiation of undifferentiated cells in an embryo." This just illustrates that words are coined, used in different contexts, get contorted in the public mind by political and religious misuse (Lysenko, anyone?), but that most English-speaking professional scientists manage to live with their scientific usage, understanding what they mean. The structure of a compound word coined in German, for example, is clear to German speakers. English speakers often neither know or care about the structure of words from Greek or Latin.

Comment: @David I don't understand the point of your last comment, but I'm not a professional scientist (still a student), and my mother tongue isn't English either, so sorry again about all that mess. Anyway, I don't really see how to improve my question. What I don't understand is that epigenetics phenomena are supposed to be heritable, while apparently those changes are erased after fertilization... which doesn't make sense to me. I don't really care about the origin of the word "epigenetics", I just would like to understand how changes can be inherited and erased at the same time.

Comment: @BryanKrause — Not nice, saying that I have a narrow view on the suitability of questions. I not only exercised my right/duty to maintain the standards of the site, but explained to the poster my reasons for doing so, something I am not obliged to do. I refered the poster to the SE Help, as the source of information on posting good questions, and told him how to find the origin of the word himself, together with naming a SE site that is more appropriate — SE EL&U *does* take questions on technical English.

Comment: OK. If that's your question, I'll edit it in that direction. Perhaps @BryanKrause will add further, and then I'll withdraw my close vote.

Comment: @David Thanks for editing it. I just made it "sound" a little bit more like I would have written it. Hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have done a presentation in epigenetics and the main topic was imprinting.
This paper will answer all your questions https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3941233/
I am adding some glimpses from this  paper here
Mammals are diploid organisms whose cells possess two
matched sets of chromosomes, one inherited from the mother
and one from the father. Thus, mammals have two copies of
every gene. Normally both the maternal and paternal copy of
each gene has the same potential to be active in any cell.
Genomic imprinting is an epigenetic mechanism that changes
this potential because it restricts the expression of a gene to
one of the two parental chromosomes. It is a phenomenon
displayed by only a few hundred of the approximately 25,000
genes in our genome, the majority being expressed equally
when inherited from either parent. Genomic imprinting affects
both male and female offspring and is, therefore,[image] a consequence
of parental inheritance, not of sex. As an example of
what is meant by this, an imprinted gene that is active on a
maternally inherited chromosome will be active on the maternal
chromosome and silent on the paternal chromosome in
all males and females.

Hope this help and please ask if you do not understand the paper.Thank you